# read.csv when file is used and open in excel

Tags: r, read.csv

example code:

```
df <- read.csv2("example_file.csv")
```

I get the following error because the file is opened with microsoft excel. (in this case by another person whom the file is shared with)

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'example_file.csv': Permission denied
```

In stead of regularly asking someone to close the file, is there another way to still read the csv file within Rstudio?

I tried the csv.read function, I expected R to read the datafile but it resulted in an error

Comment: [The options here seem relevant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-file-is-locked-for-editing-6fa93887-2c2c-45f0-abcc-31b04aed68b3).